# Validate captcha before logging

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to validate a captcha image before validating the user.
In order to validate the captcha I have created the following class that will process `POST` requests from `/mvc/login`

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;


public class CaptchaAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    
    private String processUrlString;
    
    protected CaptchaAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        this.processUrlString=defaultFilterProcessesUrl;
    }
    

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req =(HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res =(HttpServletResponse) response;
        logger.info("doFilter.method " + req.getMethod() + " .doFilter.getRequestURI " + req.getRequestURI());
        if(processUrlString.equals(req.getRequestURI()) && "POST".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
            String expected = req.getSession().getAttribute("captcha").toString();
            req.getSession().removeAttribute("captcha");
            if (expected!=null && !expected.equals(req.getParameter("answer"))) {
                unsuccessfulAuthentication(req, res, new InsufficientAuthenticationException("Wrong code"));
                return;
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        return null;
    }

}
```

In order to associate the filter to the requests I have created the following configuration class, where I specified the filter to use with: `addFilterBefore`

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.UserBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new CaptchaAuthenticationFilter("/mvc/login"), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/mvc/login").permitAll() // Is this necessary?
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/mvc/index")
                .usernameParameter("j_user")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService users() {
        UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
        UserDetails user = users
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

Am I following the right path in order to validate the request? Or should I follow a different strategy?

One issue that I have detected is that with every logging attempt it is displaying the following request `doFilter.method POST .doFilter.getRequestURI /mvc/error` instead of `doFilter.method POST .doFilter.getRequestURI /mvc/login`

This is my login form too:

```html
  <form action="/mvc/login" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="j_user" name="j_user">
  <input type="text" id="j_password" name="j_password">
  <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer">
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like right way to validate captcha. Most likly CSRF filter in intercepting the request and because of missing CSRF, it is redrecting you to error page (URL) that you see in the logs.